# Handling numbering between two different sections in angular js

Tags: angularjs, arrays, numbers

I have an array wherein I get the json response and have added a numbering(1,2,3...)(using {{index+1}} to those values. The page is divided into two sections wherein I have used the numbering separately for two different sections. Now the issue is , i wanted to move any of the items from first section into second section or vice versa such that the numbering also maintains its order. (1,2,3,4..). I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: use $index . you are using 'index'.

Comment: also try adding some code if you are looking for help.

Comment: hmm... so you want to the number to keep unchanged or changed upon moving?

Answer (score 0):

For suppose your JSON response is `$scope.results`

In `HTML` you are doing currently(First section)

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="result in results">
  {{$index}} {{result.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Modifying first section code as follows

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="result in results">
  {{result.i}} {{result.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Maintain 'i' value in controller, after you get results from JSON response do this

```
  angular.forEach($scope.results, function(result, responseIndex) {
    result.i = responseIndex;
  });
```

In controller, you write a method after move(eg: on drag & drop, call a method after drop)

```
$scope.drop = function () {
  angular.forEach($scope.results, function(result, resultIndex) {
    result.i = resultIndex;
  });
};
```

Do same in second section too

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="secResult in secResults">
  {{secResult.i}} {{secResult.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

In drag method add code

```
$scope.drop = function () {
  angular.forEach($scope.results, function(result, resultIndex) {
    result.i = resultIndex;
  });
  angular.forEach($scope.secResults, function(secResult, secResultIndex) {
    secResult.i = secResultIndex;
  });
};
```

I don't think this is good approach, truth is I don't like my answer. We will try to find best..